# use localStorage with a remove()

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
function eraseValue()
{
var ele = document.getElementById('docu');
var p = ele.remove();
}
```

I want to save p in the localStorage in order that when I refresh the page, the div 'docu' didn't appear anymore.

Comment: You could just try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.

Comment: Since you have to use JS to read/write local storage each time anyway, why not reduce the JS to just `document.getElementById('docu').remove();`?

Comment: the element will not remain removed when you refresh the page!

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage` properly at this context to achieve what you want (*the div 'docu' didn't appear anymore*)

```
var doc = document.getElementById('docu');
doc.style.display = localStorage.getItem("eraseDoc") === "true" ? "none" : "block";

function eraseValue(){
  localStorage.setItem("eraseDoc","true");
  doc.style.display = "none";
}
```

So when you call eraseValue, the div `docu` will be disappeared. And it will not appear in the page until the `localStorage` value removed or changed.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gfps0hv3/)

Comment: I think this best answers the question considering its impossible to keep an element removed after refresh. This mimics the required functionality.

Comment: You will have to be careful and put the first two lines of this code AFTER the HTML of the body so that the element in question is already loaded when that code runs.